# Server side template compiling with Ember and Node

Tags: node.js, ember.js

I am trying to convert to server sider template compiling instead of client side n my Ember Application. I am using the latest version of Ember and Handlebars and the ember-template-compiler npm package.
Myquestion is how do i render the template on the client side after it has been compiled.(or assign it to my views in my emberapp.js file)

Comment: You have to put in some effort yourself first. What have you tried whats the exact issue you're running into? ps. google ember fast boot.

Comment: Well i got the npm package and manage to compile a template and save it to a .js file and this where i got stuck, i dont know how to proceed from here.
ps: i havent used tools like ember-cli or ember-grunt before

Comment: Ah I understand what you mean. your best bet would be to try and move to ember-cli. Forget what I said about fast boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'd say use [ember-cli](http://ember-cli.com), because it handles that for you seamlessly.

But if you cannot, you need to precompile your templates and set them on the `Ember` namespace, i.e.

```
// browserify example
Ember.TEMPLATES['application'] = require('./pods/application/template.hbs');
```

And then you would add that to your `index.html` as a separate script.

A couple resources to look at are [hbsify](https://github.com/epeli/node-hbsfy) and [emberate](https://github.com/AppGeo/emberate).

Once again, you will save lots of time and have access to a whole community of addons ([1](http://www.emberaddons.com/), [2](http://emberobserver.com/)) if you use ember-cli, which will be the official way to use Ember in a couple months, even the docs are being updated for it.